# Printing out the value of pointer to the first index of an char array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I'm new to C++ and is trying to learn the concept of pointer. When I tried to print out the value of pStart, I was expecting its value to be the address of text[0] in hexdecimal (e.g. something like 0x7fff509c5a88). However, the actual value printed out is abcdef.

Could someone explain it to me why this is the case? What parts am I missing?

```
char text[] = "abcdef";
char *pStart = &text[0]; 
cout << "value of pStart: " << pStart << endl;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iostreams provide an overload that assumes a pointer to char points to a NUL-terminated (C-style) string, and prints out the string it points to.

To get the address itself to print out, cast it to a pointer to void instead:

```
cout << "value of pStsart: " << (void *)pStart << "\n";
```

Note that you don't really need `pStart` here at all though. The name of an array (usually, including this case) evaluates to the address of the beginning of the array, so you can just print it directly:

```
cout << "address of text: " << (void *)text << "\n";
```

Get out of the habit of using `endl` as well. It does things you almost certainly don't realize and almost never want.